# Why do I get a different scale for a column when I look in table design and script table vs information_schema and sys.columns?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ddl, information-schema

I need to be able to identify (in code) the scale of a sql server column.
For all of the numeric columns, I get a different answer for scale, depending on where I look for it.

For example if I go the the table designer I will see that a particular column is numeric(17,2). If I go to "Script table as" -> "Create to" -> "New Query window", then I also see that it is numeric (17,2).

However, if I go to information_schema, or sys.columns, I see a precision value of 17 (which is fine) but a scale value of 10 (sys.columns.scale or information_schema.columns.numeric_scale) (which is wrong).

The correct answer is definitely (17,2), but I don't seem to have a way of determining this in my code. Is there some other place I should be looking?

Comment: What do "system_type_id" and "user_type_id" say? I can't repro on SQL Server 2016 13.0.5216

Comment: Both say 108, which corresponds to numeric (with max scale 38) on sys.types.

Comment: Do you have a table with the same name in a different schema? In the correct database? etc...

Comment: "select * from sys.tables where name = 'mytable'" shows only one record. Is that conclusive? I didn't build the database, btw.

Comment: is there a view. This also has a sys.columns entry. Check sys.objects

Comment: "select * from sys.objects where name = 'mytable'" returns one record which is type_desc =USER_TABLE

Comment: No idea then (SSMS or SMO bug maybe) sys.columns is correct